# awk: print values of one field on another field

Tags: awk, field

I have a csv file with 2 fields: date ($1) and daily temperatures throughout the year ($2) and I want to extract the temperatures from April to September, but each month on another column like this:

| April | May |
| --- | --- |
| 17 C | 20 C |
| 15 C | 22 C |
| 15 C | 21 C |
| ... |  |

Using the following command I get a temp.csv file with all temperatures in a single column:

```
awk ' /2020-04/  {print $2}' year-temperatures.csv >> temp.csv
awk ' /2020-05/  {print $2}' year-temperatures.csv >> temp.csv
awk ' /2020-06/  {print $2}' year-temperatures.csv >> temp.csv
```

What should be done to put each month be in another column?

Comment: could you show the raw file `year-temperatures.csv` or a part of it?

Comment: Give `paste` a ride.

Comment: Replace your graphic table with raw text. We can't copy/paste an image to test with. Also add the expected output as text.

Comment: Sorry but i don't know how to paste and keep the table format

Comment: I'm thinking about answering, but first: do you have GNU awk?

Comment: "keep the table format" -- you probably just need preformatted text. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help. Also, showing some sample data doesn't have to be pretty, we want to see the raw source data.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following script (`temperature.awk`):

```
BEGIN {
   SUBSEP="@"
}
{
        month=0+substr($1,6,2);
        day=0+substr($1,9,2);
        a[month,day]=$2;
}
END{
        printf("%5s ","")
        for (month=1; month<=12; month++) {
                printf("%5s ", month);
        }
        printf("\n");
        for (day=1; day<=31; day++) {
                printf("%4s: ", day)
            for (month=1;month<=12; month++) {
                    printf("%5s ", a[month,day])
            }
            printf("\n")
         }
 }
```

When doing: `gawk -F, -f temperature.awk year-temperatures.csv >> temp.csv`

Your `temp.csv` should look sometheing like this (with my test data):

```
          1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11    12
   1:  17.5  19.9  21.5  19.6  18.7  14.2  18.5  18.9  15.9  14.3  21.4  21.4
   2:  18.6  20.7  17.6    14  12.7  13.4  17.1  12.3  21.6  17.3  18.8  12.8
   3:  18.3  21.8  21.8  19.1  15.6  12.5    18  12.8  18.5  21.7  17.6  17.8
   4:    14  14.7  13.9  21.6    18  20.3  16.8    15  15.7  14.4  19.5  18.7
   5:  12.7  16.3  12.3  18.7  20.9  12.1  18.1  14.5  21.1    15  12.6  18.1
   6:  19.7  15.2  17.7  16.5  18.6  17.4  17.9  15.4  16.4  19.9  12.7  12.2
   7:  18.3  15.1  19.7  14.6  18.2  18.7  13.2  21.8  16.5  12.4  13.8    15
   8:  20.2  18.2  13.5  21.3  13.4  19.4  20.2  20.6  21.5  20.3  18.7  16.2
   9:  14.4  13.4  16.4  20.8  20.3  18.8  19.5  15.7  15.7  12.4  20.3  14.1
  10:  19.4  20.7  19.3  18.2  19.4    14  14.9  14.7  12.2  19.1  13.2    20
  11:  21.8  21.2  15.2  16.7    14  21.4  14.1  14.5  12.1  16.3  13.4  15.8
  12:  18.8  21.9  16.2  16.7    20  13.3  13.8  16.2  21.6  12.2  15.1  16.8
  13:  16.5    14  13.4  21.5    16    20  14.7  15.5  19.7    20  13.4  14.7
  14:  14.3  12.2  16.2  15.5    18  18.1    20    17  21.9  21.3  19.9  21.2
  15:    20  16.9  19.1  21.1  19.7  18.4  14.1  16.3  18.5  14.6  17.2  19.7
  16:  15.1  16.1  14.8  16.9  12.8  15.8  18.2  18.5  14.7  16.9  14.1  13.1
  17:  13.3  17.7  14.7  19.2  12.9  21.6  16.8  21.6  16.2    19  17.1  14.1
  18:  19.5  18.3  17.3  13.3  14.2  18.9  17.4  20.4  14.6  12.4  21.3  19.5
  19:  15.4  16.3  20.1  16.8  20.2  17.6  14.4  15.4  12.6  12.8    13    13
  20:  16.8  14.7  16.6  12.2  16.2  19.3    18  13.8    17  14.9    19  14.5
  21:  15.4  12.4  20.6  18.6  18.7  21.8  14.7  20.6  15.1  13.9  14.1  21.8
  22:  14.9  16.1  21.4  14.4  12.8  19.2  17.5  19.5  12.8  12.7  21.5  13.1
  23:  16.3  21.1  12.9  14.3  16.1  18.6  21.3  13.9  16.6  20.2  13.2  18.5
  24:  14.9  15.3  18.7  16.3  19.8  13.5  12.1    19  12.7  20.5  19.5  20.9
  25:  13.3    21  12.5  16.5  18.9  19.4  14.8  21.3  21.5  20.2  15.9    17
  26:    20  17.4  14.4  21.7  12.8  14.6  15.5  17.4  17.5  17.5  18.9  20.2
  27:    18    12  12.5  17.1  15.7  12.9    21  21.2  20.8    15  14.8  18.3
  28:  17.9  15.9  17.6  18.2  17.7  18.5  16.7  21.8  19.6  20.2  15.6  18.7
  29:  13.8        18.2  17.9  19.7  21.7  18.6  13.4  13.7  14.1  21.2  16.7
  30:  13.1        16.1  12.9  13.3  21.1  20.9  19.5  17.5    18  17.4  15.3
  31:  12.3          14        15.2        16.7  15.3        15.5        14.4
```

The first couple of lines from my testdata look like this:

```
2022-01-01, 17.5
2022-01-02, 18.6
2022-01-03, 18.3
2022-01-04, 14
2022-01-05, 12.7
2022-01-06, 19.7
2022-01-07, 18.3
2022-01-08, 20.2
```